# iPad Mini background refresh not working, other devices also running iOS 8.1 work fine

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, background

I am fetching the location in the background and sending it to a server. It seems like my code works fine for all devices except iPad Mini (all device are iOS 8.1). It's sending data only for 15 to 20 minutes.

Comment: When you say "background" do you mean background thread while the app is running in foreground or after the user has left the app and is doing something else? Also, perhaps you should show us how you're doing this background location fetching and sending it to the server. It's hard for us to offer suggestions if you don't tell us what you're doing and how you're doing it.

Comment: Also, you say "works fine for all device except iPad mini": What are the other devices (e.g. are you saying it works on full size iPad and not mini? or are you saying that it works on phones and iPod Touches, but not iPads?)?

Comment: HEY ROB thanks for responding ,its work on full size ipad , except ipad mini

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your iPad mini doesn't have GPS, only cellular version have it

Comment: its cellular version , its sending data until 15 to 20 min later its stops sending data